# como puedo usar los nombres de las paginas de wordpress como texto del header?

Tags: wordpress

buenas, estoy intentando que en cada pagina de wordpress en vez de salirme en el header el texto que sale en la home aparezca el nombre de la pagina en concreto, alguien sabe si es posible y como? llevo dias buscando informacion pero no hay manera.

Comment: Hola JHZ, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. ¿Puedes mostrar tus intentos y lo que has investigado? Pon tambien los problemas o errores concretos para que sobre ello podamos ayudarte. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar tu pregunta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a la etiqueta  existen algunos plugins principalmente orientados a SEO que permiten cambiar el título para cada página, entrada, archivo multimedia entre otros de los posibles, gran parte de estos plugins permite personalizar las meta tags. También puedes editar en tu archivo header de la plantilla, localiza en wp-content/mitema/header.php la siguiente etiqueta:

```
<title></title>
```

Si existe la eliminas junto a su contenido y te diriges a tu archivo functions.php para insertar lo siguiente si es que no existe:

```
    if ( ! function_exists( '_wp_render_title_tag' ) ) :
     function theme_slug_render_title() {
    ?>
    <title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <?php
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'theme_slug_render_title' );
    endif;
```

De lo contrario si está presente en el header.php o quieres agregarla insertas en tu functions.php

```
  add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

Y en el header.php:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

El método **wp_title()** lo puedes ver en https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/

Ahora si te refieres a un título por ejemplo que está junto al menú, logotipo o en una ubicación similar posiblemente en el archivo header.php encuentres algo como

```
<div id="site-header">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <?php echo esc_attr(get_bloginfo('name')); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

En donde puedes cambiar  por:

```
<div id="site-header">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <?php echo esc_attr(get_the_title()); ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Referencia: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/